# Pod errors: CrashLoopBackOff from kubernetes while after deploying mojaloop on my cont

Tags: kubernetes

After deploying mojaloop on my Kubernetes cont while some of mojaloop service is showing with status crashloopback

```
sudo kubectl describe pod moja-centraldirectory-ff9d88c44-rrm2q  --namespace demo
```

```html
Name:           moja-centraldirectory-ff9d88c44-rrm2q
Namespace:      demo
Priority:       0
Node:           mojaloop/178.128.166.214
Start Time:     Fri, 01 Nov 2019 11:53:20 +0000
Labels:         app=moja-centraldirectory
                chart=centraldirectory-3.4.2
                heritage=Tiller
                pod-template-hash=ff9d88c44
                release=moja
Annotations:    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.80.147/32
Status:         Running
IP:             192.168.80.147
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/moja-centraldirectory-ff9d88c44
Init Containers:
  wait-for-postgres:
    Container ID:   docker://533d708b40eac27be3f1c73fa8403bc03573214622980ca7a8da71edf89f3fa5
    Image:          bowerswilkins/awaitpostgres
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://bowerswilkins/awaitpostgres@sha256:62b93d2fb6d05e7a0a39f40895df59c5f7e80d4292690709b374d66f5456e911
    Port:           &lt;none&gt;
    Host Port:      &lt;none&gt;
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 05 Nov 2019 06:05:39 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 05 Nov 2019 06:05:39 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  5
    Environment:
      POSTGRES_URL:  postgresql://central-directory:gR5hARbsfa@moja-centraldirectory-postgresql:5432/central_directory?sslmode=disable
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5v2gl (ro)
Containers:
  centraldirectory:
    Container ID:   docker://5936901d7eb7848362b8317866143ce9b13c7c096c6a318e78af6825d0d38cc8
    Image:          mojaloop/central-directory:v2.4
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mojaloop/central-directory@sha256:c25ca28a13dfbaca8590f7a9fb512a09f42b389c2ff5ab63edb2b829fda319ae
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 05 Nov 2019 06:06:32 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 05 Nov 2019 06:06:32 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1062
    Liveness:       http-get http://:3000/health delay=60s timeout=1s period=15s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:3000/health delay=60s timeout=1s period=15s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      CDIR_DATABASE_URI:                       &lt;set to the key &apos;db.uri&apos; in secret &apos;moja-centraldirectory&apos;&gt;                                    Optional: false
      CDIR_ADMIN_KEY:                          &lt;set to the key &apos;cdir.admin.key&apos; of config map &apos;moja-centraldirectory&apos;&gt;                        Optional: false
      CDIR_ADMIN_SECRET:                       &lt;set to the key &apos;cdir.admin.secret&apos; of config map &apos;moja-centraldirectory&apos;&gt;                     Optional: false
      CDIR_PATHFINDER__PROVISIONING__ADDRESS:  &lt;set to the key &apos;cdir.pathfinder.provisioning.address&apos; of config map &apos;moja-centraldirectory&apos;&gt;  Optional: false
      CDIR_PATHFINDER__QUERY__ADDRESS:         &lt;set to the key &apos;cdir.pathfinder.query.address&apos; of config map &apos;moja-centraldirectory&apos;&gt;         Optional: false
      CDIR_PATHFINDER__QUERY__PORT:            &lt;set to the key &apos;cdir.pathfinder.query.port&apos; of config map &apos;moja-centraldirectory&apos;&gt;            Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /opt/central-directory/config from moja-centraldirectory-config-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5v2gl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  moja-centraldirectory-config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      moja-centraldirectory
    Optional:  false
  default-token-5v2gl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-5v2gl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  &lt;none&gt;
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                     From               Message
  ----     ------          ----                    ----               -------
  Warning  BackOff         8m10s (x4393 over 15h)  kubelet, mojaloop  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  FailedMount     2m56s                   kubelet, mojaloop  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume &quot;default-token-5v2gl&quot; : couldn&apos;t propagate object cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount     2m55s (x2 over 2m56s)   kubelet, mojaloop  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume &quot;moja-centraldirectory-config-volume&quot; : couldn&apos;t propagate object cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Normal   SandboxChanged  2m20s (x2 over 2m53s)   kubelet, mojaloop  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  BackOff         113s                    kubelet, mojaloop  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling         98s (x2 over 2m18s)     kubelet, mojaloop  Pulling image &quot;bowerswilkins/awaitpostgres&quot;
  Normal   Pulled          97s (x2 over 2m16s)     kubelet, mojaloop  Successfully pulled image &quot;bowerswilkins/awaitpostgres&quot;
  Normal   Created         96s (x2 over 2m16s)     kubelet, mojaloop  Created container wait-for-postgres
  Normal   Started         96s (x2 over 2m15s)     kubelet, mojaloop  Started container wait-for-postgres
  Normal   Pulling         76s (x2 over 96s)       kubelet, mojaloop  Pulling image &quot;mojaloop/central-directory:v2.4&quot;
  Normal   Pulled          75s (x2 over 94s)       kubelet, mojaloop  Successfully pulled image &quot;mojaloop/central-directory:v2.4&quot;
  Normal   Created         75s (x2 over 94s)       kubelet, mojaloop  Created container centraldirectory
  Normal   Started         74s (x2 over 94s)       kubelet, mojaloop  Started container centraldirectory
  Warning  BackOff         73s (x3 over 91s)       kubelet, mojaloop  Back-off restarting failed contain
```

The pod is replying with status of crashloopback
 The above logs is out put while describing the pod for moja-centraldirectory-ff9d88c44-rrm2q , i am new to kubernttes if any can help me on this issue i would be happy

Comment: Attached logs is based on describe pod :

Comment: can you share status of contianer belong to pod ?

Comment: there are no attached logs...

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan here the logs from after using the above command

Comment: logs , I didnot see any logs  @dan

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan i have shared you the logs

Comment: @MarkusDresch i have attached the logs

Comment: please share container logs : `docker logs 5936901d7eb7848362b8317866143ce9b13c7c096c6a318e78af6825d0d38cc8`?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan  here is the logs based on the shared command                                "2019/11/05 06:05:39 Connected to postgres!"

Comment: @dan cold you share your YAML for this deployment? Also please provide more information about what you want to achieve. As few of the events are `FailedMount` I guess you want to bind this pod with PV. Could you also share those (PV) YAML?